# An API links with {query} at the end

Tags: heroku

I was trying to create a project with an API that I found. which the API is https://consumet-api.herokuapp.com/manga/mangadex/%7Bquery%7D and it have {query} at the end so I try erase the {query} to see what happen. the links now is https://consumet-api.herokuapp.com/manga/mangadex/ . And I found out that there is no difference with query or without query. The object properties stay the same, the only difference is the data of the properties change.

```
Link with {query} at the end https://consumet-api.herokuapp.com/manga/mangadex/%7Bquery%7D

title : The Legend of Zelda Gaiden: Quark and the Fairy Queen
```

And

```
Link without {query} at the end https://consumet-api.herokuapp.com/manga/mangadex/

title : A Good life.
```

So what is difference between a {query} and non {query} in the API?

Sorry if you find this question stupid, I'm just curious about it.

Answer (score 2):

the way consumet works is like this:
You have the base url, in this case https://consumet-api.herokuapp.com/manga/mangadex/ 
then you just append the name of the manga you want to search for
e.g.
https://consumet-api.herokuapp.com/manga/mangadex/jujutsu-kaisen

{query} means you have to add some kind of string to the url

Comment: But why it show difference data {query) and without {query}. In the (query) one, It show 24 data with difference title then without {query} one.